# Symfony2: How to include a js file inside another js?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony

I am using [intl-tel-input](https://github.com/Bluefieldscom/intl-tel-input#demo-and-examples) plugin in a Symfony project. We currently combine Assets in order to load all js script files into one.

However the intl-tel-input plugin requires utils.js in order to enable formatting/validation etc. and it needs to be included inside the script, like this:

```
utilsScript: "/Resources/js/vendors/utils.js"
```

However if I use that I get a 404 error (file utils.js not found).

How can I load that file on the script?

This is my complete script:

```
$(".js-phone").intlTelInput({
    autoFormat: false,
    autoHideDialCode: false,
    autoPlaceholder: true,
    defaultCountry: "auto",
    geoIpLookup: function(callback) {
      $.get('http://ipinfo.io', function() {}, "jsonp").always(function(resp) {
        var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
        callback(countryCode);
      });2
    },
    nationalMode: false,
    utilsScript: "{{ include('/Resources/js/vendors/utils.js') }}" // utils.js enables formatting/validation etc. 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation you provided `utilsScript` requires path to `js` file. You can't just use `/Resources/js/vendors/utils.js` since `Resources` is not a public directory.

Twig's `include` is meant to **INCLUDE** file contents, so what you need to use is `asset` function:

```
$(".js-phone").intlTelInput({
    (..)
    utilsScript: "{{ asset('bundles/yourbundle/js/vendors/utils.js') }}" 
});
```